# Silverstripe Limit Upload

Tags: php, image, silverstripe

I am using ImageDataObjectManager to handle uploading my images. I'd like to limit the ability to upload more than one image. Currently I have:

```
$bannerManager = new ImageDataObjectManager(
    $this,
    'CustomBanner',
    'CustomBanner',
    'Banner', 
    array(
    ),
    'getCMSFields_forPopup'
);

$bannerManager->setUploadLimit(1);
```

This limits the upload until I save the page. Then it allows me to add another image, which I wouldn't like it to.

Can anyone help?

Edit: I Managed to remove the uploader from showing in the popup with:

```
    if($this->CustomBanners()->Count() >= 1){
        $bannerManager->removePermission('add');
    }
    else{
        $bannerManager->addPermission('add');
    }
```

However, this doesn't hide the add button. Does anyone know how to make the add button hide too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `FileDataObjectManager` instead of `ImageDataObjectManager`:

```
$bannerManager = new FileDataObjectManager(
    $this,
    'CustomBanner',
    'CustomBanner',
    'Banner', 
    array(
    ),
    'getCMSFields_forPopup'
);

$bannerManager->setUploadLimit(1);

if($this->CustomBanners()->Count() >= 1){
    $bannerManager->removePermission('add');
}
```